What is the standard deviation in photon number for a squeezed coherent state?
I would appreciate if someone could provide some reference publication with such result.
Edit: I cannot understand why this got flagged as homework, when it clearly isn't- it is a reference request, since after reading bibliography about it I am not able to find any reputable source with the result I am looking for

In case you only need a reference to the literature, I can't help because I don't know any. But a squeezed coherent state is a relatively simple thing, the answer to the main question can be obtained simply from the definition of such a state and the properties of the creation-annihilation operators. This is probably the reason it was marked as a homework.

“after reading bibliography”… what bibliography? These states are very common and their properties either well known or easy to obtain.

The wikipedia article contains information on how to compute expectation values of combinations of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ in a squeezed coherent state, which is what you need to do as well (you want an expectation value of $N^\dagger N = a^\dagger a a^\dagger a$).
